# How is energy consumed when charging a battery?

Tags: battery-charging, charging

When I charge my battery at a constant voltage and current, the energy supplied is constant throughout the charging process. If it takes 1h to charge to 80%, the next 20% takes another 1h.

Since I supplied the same amount of electrical energy during the first and second one-hours, is a significant part of energy wasted during the second one-hour?

I understand the battery internal resistance increases by the degree of charge. Does it mean we waste a significant of the electrical energy supplied in the form of heat?

Comment: How are you measuring "%age complete" and "constant voltage and current"? Lots of charging systems reduce the charge current towards the end. And "fuel gauge" systems are notoriously inaccurate.

Comment: @pjc50 good point indeed. Assume we are using a plain power supply with constant voltage and current. How will be the charging behavior?

Comment: you do waste some in heat, how much is "significant" is an opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since I supplied the same amount of electrical energy during the first
>   and second one-hours, is a significant part of energy wasted during
>   the second one-hour?

Your assumptions are wrong. Take a Lithium Ion battery for instance: -

[image]

[Picture source](http://www.batterypoweronline.com/articles/how-to-charge-li-ion-with-a-parasitic-load/).

In stage 1 capacity rises linearly with time because the current is constant. When stage 2 occurs (the terminal voltage reaches a set-point) capacity rises more slowly and tails off just as the charging current tails off.

In other words in stage 1 there is roughly a constant wattage pumped into the battery but during stage 2 that wattage gradually reduces as current falls.